# NodeJs Express - How to return HTTP ERROR CODE (400,401,500) plus JSON OBJECT

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a web api which is using express and NodeJs. This sounds really basic but I could not found a solution. How can I return a response with http status code and Json object?

For example:

**res.send(500, {success: false, error 'Sorry, error'});**

Even if I return an error http response code, I would like to return a json object. I am trying to use some request methods, but no one of them give the option to set http status code and json object.

I am pretty sure that I might be missing something, because this is really basic for a web api framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As per the Express (Version 4+) docs, you can use:

```
res.status(400);
res.send('Response');
```

You can add a status code with your response like this

```
res.status(500).json({success: false, error 'Sorry, error'});
```

Answer (score 8):

You could do something like this

```
res.json({ user: 'tobi' })//sends a json only
res.status(500).json({ error: 'message' })//sends json with status code
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue but I finally solved it with something very simple

```
res.status(400).json({error:"error message here"})
```

This worked although at the Network on chrome 200 appeared